# jQuery `$().prepend();` not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, prepend

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/kBD3X/2/) is the fiddle.

I am trying to make a comment system by getting the value of `<textarea id='type'></textarea>` and prepend it as a div. The JS is currently:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#b').click(function(){
        var v = $('#type').val();
        $('div').prepend(v);
    });
});
```

---

```
<h1>Comments</h1>

<textarea id='type'></textarea>
<br />
<br />
<button id='b' onclick='comment()'>Submit</button>
```

But for some reason this code isn't showing the prepended var.

**Edit**

I have updated to have div but had already tried it. It didn't show up.

Comment: where is your div ?Here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/wsxMj/

Comment: @FaceOfJock This fiddle does not work for me.

Comment: it's working , please vote to this comment to confirm it's working

Comment: check your developer console, you've got 2 event handlers attached to "b"

Comment: Ahhhh. now they are working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/charaf11/wsxMj/)

I added a div with `id='div1'` because you try to prepend to `undefined` `div`.

Also styled your div with `color:white` so that you can see the text:

```
 <h1>Comments</h1>
 <textarea id='type'></textarea>
 <br />
 <br />
 <button id='b' >Submit</button>
 <div id='div1'></div>
```

**And css :**

```
#div1 {
   color:white;
 }
```

**jQuery code :**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b').click(function(){
        var v = $('#type').val();
        $("#div1").prepend(v);
    });
});
```